# How to define a triod

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm looking for a topological definition of a triod as a compact metric space. I have an intuitive idea of what it is (three intervals with one shared point being a boundary point of each interval) but no strict definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a specific “instance”, e.g. $[-1,1]\times\{0\}\cup \{0\} \times[0,1]$ as a subspace of the Euclidean plane, and define it as any space homeomorphic to it.

Comment: OK, cool, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Triod is defined [here](https://uts.nipissingu.ca/loganh/ut-thesis_LCHoehn.pdf).

> A triod is a continuum T which has
>   a subcontinuum Z such that T r Z is the union of three non-empty, mutually
>   separated sets.